# What are the pros and cons of installing a package that is not in the CRAN repository?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm specifically interested in the `data.table` package that is currently available as version 1.9.6. in [the CRAN repository](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) and verison 1.9.7. on [github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki).

What am I risking by using a package or package version that is not on CRAN?

Comment: From the installation page https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation "If you install the latest version from GitHub and start using a new feature, you may have to [yada yada caveats and warnings]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I risking by using a package or package version that is not on CRAN?

*In principle*, CRAN submissions undergo more rigorous checking and are thus of higher quality.

*In practice* there’s no evidence that this makes a difference: plenty of submissions to CRAN are of bad quality but pass the CRAN submission tests, and many actively maintained packages on Github are of high quality. I’d even go further: if the package is on Github, there’s a good chance that it is of higher quality than the average on CRAN.

For the package in question, the point is moot: [‹data.table› uses a rigorous deployment procedure and undergoes very similarly rigorous checks before being published on Github](https://gitlab.com/jangorecki/data.table/pipelines) as it undergoes for CRAN submission (though I *do* have some concerns about the package’s overall code quality, but this is besides the point).

So install it — there’s no problem.

Comment: I guess I thought submitting a package to CRAN was more involved than that. So there is no possible dependency issue? Other packages won't freak out?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien No, I just find that the general C code quality isn’t very appealing. I know it’s a widely used package so there’s probably good code coverage, but the code quality of the C code isn’t even close to what I would require to pass code review.

Comment: Linked travis builds publish package to drat repository allowing easy install dev version. Yet besides travis we do have builds on Windows (many false positives), and I also maintain various linux builds run on [GitLab CI](https://gitlab.com/jangorecki/data.table/pipelines), stated R dependency, R-devel, R vanilla.

Comment: @jangorecki Ah, thanks. My original link was just to show that continuous integration is generally happening, but your link is of course better.